# Discrepancies between output of Dictionary<int, string> and Queue<KeyValuePair<int, string>> in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, queue

Can anyone help me understand why the output of the two `for loops` below produce different outputs?

They to my eye are the same, however the original `Dictionary` object's `for loop` outputs all 9 of its members, but the `Queue` objects `for loop` outputs just the first 5.

```
void test()
{
        Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        d.Add(0, "http://example.com/1.html");
        d.Add(1, "http://example.com/2.html");
        d.Add(2, "http://example.com/3.html");
        d.Add(3, "http://example.com/4.html");
        d.Add(4, "http://example.com/5.html");
        d.Add(5, "http://example.com/6.html");
        d.Add(6, "http://example.com/7.html");
        d.Add(7, "http://example.com/8.html");
        d.Add(8, "http://example.com/9.html");

        Queue<KeyValuePair<int, string>> requestQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

        // build queue
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> dictionaryListItem in d)
        {
            requestQueue.Enqueue(dictionaryListItem);
            Console.WriteLine(dictionaryListItem.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("          ");

        for (int i = 0; i < requestQueue.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(requestQueue.Peek().Value);
            requestQueue.Dequeue();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save count before the loop:

```
var count = requestQueue.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(requestQueue.Peek().Value);
    requestQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

The reason is that it is evaluated at each iteration of the for loop:

At the start of the first iteration, `requestQueue.Count` is 9, `i` is `0`.
2nd iteration: `requestQueue.Count` is 8, `i` is `1`.
3rd iteration: `requestQueue.Count` is 7, `i` is `2`.
4th iteration: `requestQueue.Count` is 6, `i` is `3`.
5th iteration: `requestQueue.Count` is 5, `i` is `4`.
6th iteration: `requestQueue.Count` is 4, `i` is `5`. --> Exit loop.

Note: The `Count` of the queue is reduced with each iteration because `Queue.Dequeue` removes the first item in the queue and returns it to the caller.

Comment: spot on. thanks. why would this be required? would have thought requestQueue.Count would hold correct val?

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime: It does hold the correct value. Please check my answer again. You do realize that `Dequeue` removes the item from the queue?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use this `while-loop` instead which is more meaningful here:

```
while (requestQueue.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(requestQueue.Peek().Value);
    requestQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

The problem with your `for-loop` is that [`Queue.Dequeue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.dequeue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) removes the first item which also reduces the `Count` property. That's why it stops "part-way".

The loop variable `i` is still increasing whereas `Count` is decreasing.

Comment: @Rodgers and Hammertime: If, for some reason, you need an index, you could also change the for-loop to `for (int i = 0; requestQueue.Count > 0; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Because you're changing the amount of items in requestQueue every time you call requestQueue.Dequeue(). Instead store the value of count in a local and loop with that local as the upper limit.